# (Samsung J7 V) SD card app not loading app and causing errors

Tags: samsung

Two days ago, my phone randomly rebooted, all my apps in my sd card wouldn't load after that. I ended up having to reinstall them from the play store, and I got everything on them back, But one app Wouldn't install. It kept saying app not installed on google play, and if I downloaded an apk, it would ask if I wanted to update the app, and then say App Not Installed. Please help

Comment: I would suggest cleaning up using [SDMaid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm), since the app may have remnants that prevent re-installing. This is really a common solution on this StackExchange, and a common question that would have been found through rudimentary search.